# TypeError: $.fn.datagrid.methods[_6dc] is not a function

Tags: datagrid, reload, jquery-easyui

Firebug 2.0.6 is showing a jQuery type error using jquery-easyui.

I know this has been asked before and I've spent a couple of hours ploughing through answers and I'm just getting deeper and deeper.

Has anyone seen this in Firebug?

> TypeError: $.fn.datagrid.methods[_6dc] is not a function...
>  return
>   $.fn.datagrid.methods_6dc;

in http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js on line 9523

I have copied the code straight from the site as follows:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

and

```js
function destroyUser(){
  var row = $('#tblData').datagrid('getSelected');
  if (row){
    $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
      if (r){
        $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.ID},function(result){
          if (result.success){
            $('#tblData').datagrid('reload');  // reload the user data
          } else {  
            $.messager.show({  // show error message
              title: 'Error',
              msg: result.errorMsg
            });
          }
        },'json');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The function above will delete the record successfully except the `$('#tblData').datagrid('reload');` does not work.

I can't believe there is a link between these two issues. I solved the problem with      `location.reload();`, but there's surely a better way, right?